# Regarding blocking a user from asking anymore questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If amateurs and novices of any given subject can use these sites and they are not rude or abusive then why should one be blocked from asking questions. If their questions or responses are poorly worded or irritating in some way should these be censored? Unless every user of these sites has to be eloquent and non-controversial (forgive spelling). If an editor sees a question or response that is irritating or deems it a waste of time indicate it as poorly worded and move on. Do not block the writer from ever asking questions again. How can one learn if one is only allowed a finite number of questions and responses that are poor or irritating?

Comment: I assume you're running into some kind of question limit? Sometimes there are additional limitations placed on accounts that restrict them to one question/week -- perhaps you can spell out a little more clearly the problem you're encountering with the system?

Comment: Indeed, what specifically are you referring to as problematic?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Just some statement some of my question or responses were not well received and I might be blocked from asking further questions. I have never been abusive or rude. All I  can think of is some users didn't like my opinions or my trying to defend my point of view. You see if you're an amateur without much confidence you might try to defend your opinion even if it is terrible. Why are these sites open to amateurs?